# How to startX as non-root user inside the rc.local?

Tags: boot, root, x-server, openbox

I am trying to start `startx` as non-root user in my Ubuntu-server 16.04(`Linux nanopim1 3.4.113-sun8i #16 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 13 14:15:57 CEST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`) with `openbox` installed on it.

I tried to put each of these files one-by-ne inside `/rc.local` but didn't work! the only thing that is work is putting `startx` without any addition on `/etc/rc.local` and it starts as root!

```
su -l m -c startx

su -s /bin/bash -c startx m&

su - m -c startx
```

Also I tried another way, I did create a file here: `/etc/systemd/system/autologin.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Autologin service

[Service]
Type=fork
user=m
group=m
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startx
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` but didn't work again!!!

Only putting `startx` alone inside `/etc/local` works but it's `root` user that I don't want to be!

Comment: ... Why not just tell the DM to autologin?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: because I am not an advanced user and I did what other users told me inside here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403599/my-ubuntu-server-doesnt-execute-my-gtk-based-program-at-startup/406384?noredirect=1#comment727290_406384  and here  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405618/how-to-change-autologin-from-root-to-non-root-user

Answer (score 2):

**Display manager version (easier)**

It is typically the job of display manager to show a login screen and start a user session. If you had one, it would be a path of least resistance to set it up to autologin. It is a widely used and probably well tested and supported solution. You would need to set it up to 1) autologin and 2) use your preffered session, but both are typically supported with the usual display managers supported by your linux (lightdm, xdm, whatever..).

On ubuntu 16.04 (non-server) I have the following in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=xyz
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

You would need to install and possibly enable lightdm

```
apt-get install lightdm
```

Lightdm is the default ubuntu display manager. It is not installed by default on ubuntu server edition and you will be installing serveral packages so the harder manual way would be required if you wish to avoid them.

Ways of setting up a graphical login on ubuntu server is better described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui#788193, after which you can set up autologin if you wish.

You may want to select your preffed type of session (openbox), by setting `/home/username/.dmrc` to something like

```
[Desktop]
Session=openbox
```

**Manual (startx)**

I don't know what is exactly required to start an x session startx on boot, but I would suggest decomposing the problem to step-by-step process:

1. you say you startx works as root. It would be nice to verify you can log in as root on a console and start an x session with:

   ```
   root@xyz # startx
   ```
2. Make sure you can start an X session when logged in as your preffered user.

   ```
   myuser@xyz $ startx
   ```
3. Make sure you can start an X session as the preffered user, but while logged in as root, by building upon the previous command:

   a) Use something like:

   ```
   root@xyz # su -l myuser -c startx
   ```

   quote the command if you need multiple arguments:

   ```
   root@xyz # su -l myuser -c "startx arg1 arg2 .."
   ```

   b) You may be able to skip this step if you set the user in the systemd unit.
4. Make it autostart.

   a) Add the (3a) command to `/etc/rc.local` and reboot.

   b) Use a systemd unit like you described, with the command set according to 2/3. To test, you may use something like

   ```
   root@xyz # systemctl stop autologin  # make sure to reset service
   root@xyz # systemctl daemon-reload   # don't know if needed
   root@xyz # systemctl start autologin
   ```

   Once it works, you may need to enable it to autostart or whatever it is that systemd needs (not an expert).

   ```
   root@xyz # systemctl enable autologin
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I got it following the next steps:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-legacy xinit xterm
```

It is important the **legacy** package because in the last version the next command not works without it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-legacy
```

in the console menu please select **Anybody**

After that, you can launch the Xserver or any program via xinit or **startx** without root like that:

```
sudo su -l pi -c "xinit -geometry =800x400+0+0 -fn 8x13 -j -fg white -bg black /home/pi/go/bin/wego -- -nocursor" & -geometry =800x400+0+0 -fn 8x13 -j -fg white -bg black /home/youruser/bin/anyprogram -- -nocursor" &
```

or with **startx**:

```
sudo su -l pi -c startx
```